# How to turn date into timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How would i turn
2012-04-11 12:49:14
into a unixtime stamp?

I have tried

```
$time = mktime("2012-04-11 12:59:14");
```

and

```
$time = strtotime("2012-04-11 12:59:14");
```

**EDIT**
Basically on update my database adds a date/time that looks like this.

```
2012-04-11 12:49:14
```

I need it to be turned into a unix timestamp so i can use a "time ago" function i found.

My tests have revealed,

Database input -> 2012-04-11 13:22:05 which is converted into -> 1334143355 -> But the current time from(time()) is ->1334146956

I dont see why they do not match up?

Comment: In what way does your second example not work? [Looks perfect to me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BpLNII).

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You could also do it in MySQL with the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function.

Comment: I tested it by inserting data into my database that updates the date on input, then used strtotime to compare it to the current time. the result was this, bear in mind there was only around ~5 secs that is meant to be different.
Now is : 1334146484
Saved time is : 1334142872 (2012-04-11 13:14:32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with mismatched time offsets (daylight saving perhaps). It is always best to do it all in PHP or all in MySQL to avoid mismatched time offsets.

```
1334146484 - 1334142872 = 3612s = 1h 12s
```

You should use UNIX_TIMESTAMP either when inserting or retrieving the data depending on whether you prefer storing as unix timestamp or datetime -

```
INSERT INTO `table` (date_field) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-04-11 12:59:14'));

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_field) FROM `table`;
```

Comment: Also make sure that PHP and MySQL both have the same timezone/offset set. Also worth investigating the new DateTime class as it can handle timezone/offsets for you.

Comment: @liquorvicar: If you use **all** MySQL or **all** PHP, it shouldn't matter if PHP and MySQL have the same timezone. Right?

Comment: @Travesty3 - that's right but life does get easier if you have the same timezone set for both PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to also point out the MySQL function `FROM_UNIXTIME`, which is basically the opposite of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` converts a datetime value to a Unix timestamp integer, while `FROM_UNIXTIME` converts a Unix timestamp integer into a datetime value. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `$time = strtotime("2012-04-11 12:59:14");` is working just fine.

Do a

```
echo $time;
```

after your declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the difference is from being in a different timezone. The difference is more or less +1 hour form the expected result. You need to be more specific about what time you want - as in are you recording/retrieving time from your timezone, or from UTC.

Answer (score 0):

`$time = strtotime("2012-04-11 12:59:14");` is correct option.